# Android Unit Testing of Categories

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to be able to have two (or multiple) test tasks for my Android project, where the difference is a different set of Junit Categories to include/exclude.

Using the gradle java plugin, I can do something like

```
task testFast(type: Test) {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'foo.Fast'
        excludeCategories 'foo.Slow'
    }
}

task testSlow(type: Test) {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'foo.Slow'
        excludeCategories 'foo.Fast'
    }
}
```

However, if using the android plugin, I have to add testOptions to the android closure to include/exclude,

```
android {
...
    testOptions {
        unitTests.all {
            useJUnit {
                excludeCategories foo.Slow'
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

but of course that applies to all test tasks for all build variants.

Is there a way to create tasks that use the same build variant, but execute tests on different categories?

Answer (score 9):

Best I've come up with is to use a gradle property from the command line:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.all {
        useJUnit {
            if (project.hasProperty('testCategory') && testCategory == "Slow") {
                includeCategories 'foo.Slow'
            } else {
                excludeCategories 'foo.Slow'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use

```
gradlew -PtestCategory=Slow test
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution that that did not require an extra gradle property, so I came up with this. You do need to make sure that you only ever execute at most one of the test tasks in a single run, though.

I'm hoping the android plugin will make this easier in future releases.

```
task testFast(dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest')
task testSlow(dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest')

gradle.taskGraph.whenReady { taskGraph ->
    def testTask = tasks.getByName("testDebugUnitTest")

    if (taskGraph.hasTask(tasks.getByName("testFast"))) {
        testTask.useJUnit {
            includeCategories 'foo.Fast'
            excludeCategories 'foo.Slow'
        }
    }

    if (taskGraph.hasTask(tasks.getByName("testSlow")))
        testTask.useJUnit {
            includeCategories 'foo.Slow'
            excludeCategories 'foo.Fast'
        }
    }
}
```